# Azure Active Directory - How to restrict Backend API App Registration to a specific client App Registration

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, access-token, microsoft-identity-platform

I could be completely off basis here on how this works, but this is what I'm looking to achieve.

In AAD I have

- an App Registration called `backend-api` that represents an HTTP API
- an App Registration called `frontend-app` that represents some client (lets say a console app)
- an App Registration called `another-app` that represents nothing related to my solution

I have a console application where I put my client ID and client secret in for `frontend-app` and I can request an `access_token` with the `aud` of `backend-api`.  This is great, exactly what I want.  However, I can litterally do the same thing from `another-app` if I have the client ID and client secret for that app.  **What I would like to accomplish is that only `frontend-app` is allowed to get an `access_token` for `backend-api`.**

I'm not quite sure how to go about configuring that specific requirement.  I thought maybe I needed to add an `appRoles` entry for `allowedMemberTypes` `Application` on `backend-api` and then grant `frontend-app` that role but that didn't apply any restriction to `another-app`.  Likewise I thought maybe `backend-api` needed to have its "Require User Signin" option checked under Enterprise Applications, but I couldn't find a way to add `frontend-app` as a "user" -- probably the wrong direction anyhow.

**What's the way to tell AAD to only hand out `access_tokens` for `backend-api` (`aud` claim) if they are being requested via `frontend-app` only?**  Maybe that's a silly question, and it just doesn't work this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right path with your thinking about adding `appRoles` entry to `backend-api` and then assigning the role specifically to `frontend-app`.

Additionally, understand that enforcing this requirement that only applications coming in with this new role claim are allowed but others aren't is a responsibility of your API code.

I'll get to 2 specific approaches next. Both the approaches are explained on Microsoft Docs here - [Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-direct-authorization)

**Approach 1 - Use Application Permissions or Roles**

Configure your API application to expose a set of application permissions (or roles).

This approach is a little more declarative, as you define an application permission that needs to be assigned to any application that can call your `backend-api`.

Navigate to Azure Active Directory > App Registrations > App registration for your `backend-api` app > Manifest

Add a new application role.. using json like this:

```
"appRoles": [
{
  "allowedMemberTypes": [
    "Application"
  ],
  "displayName": "Can invoke my API",
  "id": "fc803414-3c61-4ebc-a5e5-cd1675c14bbb",
  "isEnabled": true,
  "description": "Apps that have this role have the ability to invoke my backend API",
  "value": "MyAPIValidClient"
}]
```

Assign the app permission to your frontend app

```
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId <frontendapp.ObjectId> -PrincipalId <frontendapp.ObjectId> -Id "fc803414-3c61-4ebc-a5e5-cd1675c14bbb" -ResourceId <yourbackendapi.ObjectId>
```

Authenticate your frontend app to backend api using client credentials grant, i.e. using clientId and client secret.. as you're probably already doing.

Now, in the auth token received by your backend api, you can check that the role claims collection must contain a role named "MyAPIValidClient" otherwise you can reject the call with Unauthorized exception.

**Approach 2 - Use Access Control Lists**

When your backend API receives a token, it can decode the token and extract the client's application ID from the `appid` and `iss` claims. Then it compares the application against an access control list (ACL) that it maintains.

Depending on your requirement, API might grant only a subset of full permissions or all permissions to a specific client.

This 2nd approach may seem like a simpler one for some cases, although I like the first one better as it scales well when you have multiple application permissions/roles and different level of functionality to provide based on those roles.

**Related SO Post and References**

- Related SO Post - [Is there a way to secure an Azure Function that
  will only be called from a specific Azure Logic App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407966/is-there-a-way-to-secure-an-azure-function-that-will-only-be-called-from-a-speci/55411680#55411680)
- Microsoft Docs - [Microsoft identity platform and the OAuth 2.0 client credentials
  flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-direct-authorization)

Comment: Very helpful.  So the answer summed up is.  There is no way to PREVENT AAD from handing out an `access_token` for `backend-api` from `another-app` - period. If I want to simulate that, it's up to the API code itself to do the AuthZ, specifically looking for a claim that should only exist if it was generated via `frontend-app`.

Comment: the API code itself (or a proxy along the way - e.g. API Management `<validate-jwt />` policy).  Not really relevant to the conversation, but wanted to be clear for future readers.

Comment: Also, is there any way then to prevent someone from creating their OWN application and and calling `New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment` on their own app for this specific app role?  Doesn't seem like it would keep someone bound and determined to create their own client out very long if they could just add this role themselves

Comment: @ckittel Only Administrator for Azure AD tenant will be able to do this, because application permissions require giving admin consent.. so it's not like anyone will be able to do this for their app.. it's good thinking on your part though..

Comment: perfect.  That closes the loop on my concern there.  Thank you for the specifics.  Very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create scope(s) on the backend-api with consent set to "Admins only".

any app (e.g. another-app) which requests access to the scope should be blocked unless the permission is added and the admin grants permission.

Admin can revoke the permission at any time to prevent access to the backend-api scope.