# Authorize communication between REST APIs with Azure managed identity

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-managed-identity

I have read about Azure Managed Identities and would like to create a POC involving 2 web apps: A and B. These are 2 web apps that I plan to build using C# and .net core.

App A should have an Azure managed identity associated with it and should use it when making an HTTP request to B's REST API. B should be able to verify that the request comes from A's managed identity. I haven't yet been able to find the following information:

- a guide that shows me how to make an HTTP request and provide my managed identity details with it. This would be done by A
- once I receive a request on B's side, how to verify if it has managed identity info on it and then verify that info

Comment: bit older post but I guess this is what you are looking for https://endjin.com/blog/2019/06/secure-function-to-function-authentication-in-azure-without-the-need-for-credentials

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56547808/app-service-to-app-service-auth-in-azure-using-managed-identity