# problem in azure app api (restricting access to specific client app)

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

im following this tutorial https://fluentjs.medium.com/angular-spa-and-node-js-api-with-azure-ad-for-authentication-in-2021-b2974666c2eb  to create angular app and nodejs api
in azure app registration when exposing an api even if i dont add the angular client id to it i still can get a token and authorize to the nodejs api
here i have another client id so basically im using an angular app which is not set in the nodejs expose api
[image]

here is my angular environment

[image]

and here is my nodejs config.js

[image]

how im able to get authorization to nodejs api from angular app which i dont have exposed the api to it ?

Comment: Can you brief your issue?

Comment: my issue is any registered app can access my api , but in my api in expose an api section i have only 1 application that can get access to it

Comment: You mean authorized client application?

Comment: yes  in expose an api section i added a scope and client id

Comment: And did you add the scope in the API permission blade of another application

Comment: my problem is any registered app can access the scope and api

Comment: Okay so you want your application to be accessed by the client application which you added as Authorized client application

Comment: yes exactly , i dont want any app to access my api

Comment: Create scope(s) on the backend-api with consent set to "Admins only". Any app (e.g. another-app) which requests access to the scope should be blocked unless the permission is added and the admin grants permission.

Comment: im still able to authorize from another application

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191182/azure-active-directory-how-to-restrict-backend-api-app-registration-to-a-speci

Comment: ah ok thx , i will handle it in my api

Comment: Can I post it an answer?

Comment: sure you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a **backend app and Exposed an API (Admins only)** like below:

Added Authorized client applications:

[image]

Now I tried to access the `backendapp` with the another app which is not added as client application:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID 
scope:api://backendappID/access_clientapp
grant_type:authorization_code  
code:code  
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms 
client_secret:Secret
```

And access token is generated successfully:

[image]

And using this access token, the application can access the API.

> **Note** that: You cannot prevent Azure Active Directory to restrict generating access token for backend Api from any another application. You can simulate it in the API code itself to do the Auth, specifically looking for a claim that should only exist if it was generated via client application.

**Reference:**

[oauth 2.0 - Azure Active Directory - How to restrict Backend API App Registration to a specific client App Registration - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191182/azure-active-directory-how-to-restrict-backend-api-app-registration-to-a-speci) by Rohit Saigal